# d3.js: run the same code in Angular app and on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, d3.js

I need to add some infographics into Angular 5 app. I've chosen d3.js for that. I also need to be able to do export of graphs, i.e. make SVGs with Node and wrap them inside PDF.

Fortunately it's rather simple to make code that makes d3 graph in browser work on node.js. The following lines do that...

```
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;
```

After that only minor changes to code that works in browser are required.

Obviously I don't want to have 2 copies of almost the same code, so I need a way to organize usage of the functions that create SVG (I'd prefer if that was Typescript not javascript) on both angular app side and node app side. Unfortunately I don't have to much experience in Node and don't see an easy solution for that.

Here are my questions...

1. How can I simply organize usage of functions that create SVG using d3 by angular 5 app and node.js app?
2. Maybe rendering d3.js with node isn't the best solution and there's another, that is simpler?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to not mix Node.js and Angular at all. Just use angular as the front-end framework, with node.js as the back-end framework to provide data to angular via a REST API. It doesnt make any sense to use node.js to render your angular pages. Angular is meant to take care of all the client side logic like rendering and fetching data from your REST API.

Comment: Further more, you can just import d3.js inside the angular component you wish to render it in. Just be aware direct dom manipulation is not allowed inside the angular landscape as it can cause weird behavior. When using d3.js you can't entirely escape this, but you can at least minimize the impact.

Comment: This might be useful for you when you want to use d3.js inside angular, import it like this: `import * as d3 from 'd3';` and then use the `ngAfterContentInit` life cycle hook to target a element inside the html of this component.

Comment: @enf0rcer thank you for your advices, still I dont need to launch the whole application on Node. All I need is to be able to launch functions that create SVG on angular side and on Node side. I've updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: in that case, maybe you can consider using the browser as export method. Remember, you can actually use the browser to generate a pdf. As you are already visualizing the data there, why not just print that inside a pdf? If you dont want to go that road, you can put the d3 logic in a .js file and simply load that in both angular and node.js. Or if you want to stay in the angular typescript world, you can use a node.js ts plugin to convert the ts code to js.

Comment: Webpack might be the appropriate tool for this. You can set up the configuration to produce multiple javascript bundles: one for server and one for client. You can keep your SVG functions in a separate module and import them from your Angular app and your server app.

Comment: You can use `import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';` to detect the browser, as used with SSR. Not sure of your exact requirements, but there are a few examples that may give you the right pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest the following solution.

First of all, no matter which front-end framework you actually use right now. 
If I got your idea correctly, you need to have a **picture/screenshot** of the **d3js** chart, in order to use it in **PDF in the future**. Is it correct?

You need to write a utility, to be able to open the real web page with your chart component and make a screenshot (with a resolution you want ofc) It might be a combination of the protractor with chrome-browser, for example. (there are a lot of solutions, actually, we could even use **PhantomJS**. In my experience using **Protractor** simpler and easier to implement). Also, **Protractor** has an internal feature to make screenshots of the page and save to the particular folder.

Which benefits we have following that solution:

- the only one place with a source code related to chart rendering
- 100% sure that chart view the same, as on the real web-page (with 
  other angular components)
- we don't need to find the way render SVG on the Node.JS side and etc...

The job might look like below:

- Launch some NPM/Gulp/Grunt (whatever) task to open the particular
  page of your web-app by using Protractor and Chrome browser.
- Open the dummy page with only chart component + data layer.
- Make a screenshot and save to the particular folder. Use screenshot
  of the chart inside PDF (manually or by using another tool)

Comment: Yes, you've understood correctly I need to have a picture/screenshot of the d3js chart, in order to use it in PDF in the future. Even svg will do!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on the server side, you can have an api which will generate the graphics and return the  element. You can directly plug it in the UI and also use the same function for you PDF generation.